# Can the From: header of mail() be traced back to original location?

Tags: php, email

Is it possible to trace the `From:` header in the PHP `mail()` function? Meaning if I sent it as, say, `noreply@google.com` from a server on `example.com`, could it be traced back to `example.com`?

Comment: Is your next question going to be **How can I send an untraceable email?** :p

Comment: Nope, just wondering, because I'm working on a website that sends noreply emails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to debug something you've written & you know you're not trying to break the headers, yes.  If you're trying to track down the source of some spam, OTOH, you should assume that the headers contain incorrect information.

Comment: (That is to say that any intermediate MTAs could lie, mask, *or reject* it.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this will be visible in the original message.